# Eloquent order by one-to-one-related column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Good morning everyone!
I'm using *Laravel 5.0* and *Eloquent* to build a displaying page for results of some replies on the database.
Replies are in *reservations* table, which "belongs" to *users* table since every reservation is linked to a person.

```
class Reservation extends Model {

    public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
}
```

I would like to display results, the reservations, ordered by the last name column of the user. So like:

```
$reservations = Reservation::orderBy( /*users.last_name*/ )->get();
```

But I dont'know how. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll  need to join the tables to order by a foreign column.

```
$reservations = Reservation::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'users.reservation_id')
->orderBy('users.last_name', 'asc')->get();
```